# Get the result of a Ajax function in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

In my solution that are loaded in a iFrame, I need to run some ajax function, and to get sure that the `success` function of the ajax is called, I put an `alert` to see the results.

This `alert` was never reached.

In Firebug I can see that was made a call to the URL that was set in the Ajax function, and return a JSON string, but with the values that I want.

Why my `alert` isn't reached in `success` ? 
Why my page didn't receive the new value, but in firebug I can see them ?

```
self.RecoverNewValues = function () {        
        $.ajax({
            url: "myurl?period=" + self.periodoSelecionado,
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);                        
                var trimestralRevenue = result.RevenueTotalizer.TrimestralRevenue;

            $("#qtdRevenue").text(trimestralRevenue );

            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < result.RevenueByType.length; i++) {
                var a = i + 1;
                html += "<li class='list-group-item fist-item liAgrupaTiposReceita_" + a + "'>"
                    + " <span class='pull-right'>"
                    + "         <span class='valorOrigem' id='txtTextoValorLocacao_" + a + "'>R$ " + result.RevenueByType[i].ValueDollar.formatMoney(2, ',', '.') + "</span>"
                    + " </span>"
                    + " <span class='label label-success'>" + a + "</span>"
                    + " <span id='spanDescricaoOrigemReceita_" + a + "'>" + result.RevenueByType[i].DescriptionSource+ "</span>"
                    + "</li>";
            }

            $('#iframePrincipal').contentWindow.document.body.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0].innerHTML = html;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {           
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

**ERROR**

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

**RESPONSE FROM URL CALL**

[image]

**METHOD IN CONTROLLER**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string AtualizaValoresDosTotalizadoresPeloPeriodoSelecionado(string periodo)
    {
        var biggestRevenue = biggestRevenueByType(periodo);
        var listaTotalizadores = ReceitaTotalizadores(periodo);

        var receita = new ReceitaAssunto
        {
            ReceitaPorTipoReceita = listaMaioresReceitasPorTipoReceita,
            ReceitaTotalizadores = listaTotalizadores
        };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(receita);
    }
```

This only happens in web server. Localhost works fine.

[image]

Comment: It does return a HTML page, but you're specifying a dataType of JSON. When it can't parge JSON it'll throw a parse error.

Comment: Add error: as well and see what the error is

Comment: @Wouter0100 The return is a JSON, so I do some stuff with this stuff, and load dynamically a list, like `<ul><li>thing 1</li><ul>` and then, I put it in `iframe` like.

Comment: Okay, in that case the best thing to do is add the error function and log all the 3 passed variables. Could you please update your post with these values?

Comment: @Wouter0100 Question updated. I put the whole code, and the error. This occurs only when I publish the solution in my Web Server. Localhost works fine.

Comment: What's the response of your webserver? Seems it isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @Quentin and @Wouter0100, the request are made succesfully (code 200). In Google Chrome I can saw the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <` and in Firebug is `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: Could you please open developer tools, open Network and go to the request from the script. Then "Response", does this starts with `<`? In this case it isn't valid JSON. Could you give us the response?

Comment: @Wouter0100 Looks fine for me, I updated the question with the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62333/discussion-between-wouter0100-and-lucas-santos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead put the URL like a string in Ajax, call a variable where contains the Action from your Controller

var URL = "@Html.Action("myAction", "myController")";

$.ajax({
            url: URL
...
});

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response isn't JSON but HTML which isn't supported with a dataType of JSON. Update your page to only return JSON OR remove dateType from your options. You should parse your response within JS and then fill in the dynamic list.